# Find distribution of Random Variable and prove convergence in distribution.

Tags: probability, statistics

Here is the problem that I'm solving:[image]

So a) was quite easy (if I didn't miss anything :) )
Now for b): my CDF does converge to Exp(1) when x is from 0 to n

But if x more then n my function is constant 1 and Exp(1) is not.

Would it be a good explanation if I say that when n goes to infinity, x less than n with probability 1?
Would appreciate any constructive critique of my solution and advice on explaining part b)

Comment: The post stops to make sense starting at "Now for b)".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Now for b): my CDF does converge to Exp(1) when 0n my function is constant 1 and Exp(1) is not." What do you mean exactly?

What it is written above proves that
$$ \text{Pr}(Y_n\le x)=\textbf{1}_{[0,\infty)}(x)-\textbf{1}_{[0,n)}(x)\left(1-\frac{x}{n}\right)^n.$$
Now, let us fix $x \in \mathbf{R}$, then the limit is uniquely defined by
$$\lim_{n \in \mathbf{N}}\text{Pr}(Y_n\le x)=\textbf{1}_{[0,\infty)}(x)\left(1-e^{-x}\right).$$
What is the problem here?

---

About your edit, it cannot be possible that if you fix $x>0$ then $x>n$ for all positive integers $n$, probably that's your point.

Comment: hm... the is not as I printed it... i'm trying to edit but it doesn't seem to work...

Comment: Try to write it here in comment without any copy paste..

Comment: I fixed my post. It didn't want to take "<" and ">" symbols :) Your explanation is actually perfect for me. I understand the fact, just couldn't find a good way to express it. Thank you for the answer!

Comment: You're welcome ;)